# Closed form formula for discrete sums

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Is there a general way to obtain a closed form formula for any discrete sum of the form:

$\sum_{a}^{b}f(n)$

with certain restrictions on the form of $f(n)$, much like how we can find closed form expressions for integrals given the function has an anti-derivative.

If there is no known general technique for this, I'd like to know, is it at least possible to find a general technique?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The question you ask is a much more ambitious one than the one posed by the theoretical computer scientist D. Knuth in his popular series of books "The Art of Computer Programming" (Exercise 1.2.6.63 in Volume 1: Fundamental Algorithms). I quote the entire exercise:

> **[50]** Develop computer programs for simplifying sums that involve binomial coefficients.

(Here, the code **[50]** is supposed to signal that this is a research problem at the time of writing the book!)

This "limited" version of your problem has now been studied in some detail including some path-breaking work due to Zeilberger (the theory of Wilf-Zeilberger pairs). I leave you with two references:

[1] Marko Petkovsek, Herbert Wilf and Doron Zeilberger, $A = B$.

The book $A = B$ is available for download from [here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html).

[2] Wolfram Koepf, *Hypergeometric Summation: An Algorithmic Approach to Summation and Special Function Identities*, Springer-Verlag, 2014.

---

**Edit.** In your OP, you say "much like how we can find closed form expressions for integrals given the function has an anti-derivative". This is not true: every continuous function has an antiderivative but most certainly not a closed form one. Perhaps what you mean is one may compute $\int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ if you know a function $F$ such that $F' = f$. This is what the fundamental theorem of Calculus is telling you.

The analogue of this for discrete sums would be:

> Let $f$ be a given function on natural numbers $\mathbf{N}$. Suppose that $F$ is a function defined on $\mathbf{N}$ such that $f(n) = F(n) - F(n - 1)$ for all $n \geqslant 1$. Then, for natural numbers $1 \leqslant a \leqslant b$, we have:
>   $$\sum_{n=a}^b f(n) = F(b) - F(a-1)$$

Comment: I see, so there have been studies done into special cases of the more ambitious problem. But what about a technique that will guaranteed give you a closed form expression for any sum that can have one. 
Perhaps a connection between the slope of the function and the sum, much like how the fundamental theorem of calculus connects the derivative and the integral? 
That seems to feel natural doesn't it?

Comment: The idea behind fundamental theorem of calculus is in many ways what is behind [telescoping sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). I will try to address this in an edit

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the Petkovsek, Wilf, Zeilberger book "[A=B](https://books.google.ca/books?id=A-pU8HQOWPMC)" for some techniques.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it for sure. But as I commented on knsam's post, is there no connection between the slope and the sum for the discrete case as there is for the continuous case (derivatives and integrals) ?